# how to uses ffmpeg's xfade transition filter to connect multiple video files to a single file by cshrp?

Tags: c#, .net, ffmpeg

how to uses FFmpeg's xfade transition filter to connect multiple video files to a single file by cshrp?

I find a scripts on GitHub :https://github.com/qq2225936589/xfade-ffmpeg-script , but I did not good at shell scripts.
I read the official documents and spliced the two videos. If there are more than one, my idea is to splice two by two, and then splice them into a large one. Is there a better solusion?